# water leaking into the basement from the outside bricks

Tags: water

I purchased a brand-new home March 2023.  Now I see there is water leaking through the walls of the utility room in the basement.  The builder dug up the area and external waterproofing was applied.  The hole was backfilled, and sod was placed.  They put an automatic sprinkler on and the water was hitting the bricks of the house which caused water to go into the basement again.  So, the water is still there when it rains or sprinklers come on.  I believe it is soaking through the brick.  What can I do?  I have a 12-month builder's warranty.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you know if it is brick sliding or a real brick wall?  Bricks should have weeping holes at the bottom and some kind of house/weather wrap behind them.  Bricks are not that water proof.  Have written/recorded all talks with the builder.

Comment: Do you really mean bricks?  You said "The builder dug up the area and external waterproofing was applied. The hole was backfilled, and sod was placed.".  This tells me this is below ground.  And I think, in general, bricks are not used below grade anymore.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So it sounds like the OP has cinder block foundation walls, with brick above grade?

Comment: That's what I was trying to verify.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit confusing as to what you actually have for wall of your utility room.  However it is moot, because you do have a water issue.

Document everything. Keep notes on any communication with the builder. Take picture and video of the issues and be sure they are date stamped.

Continue to communicate with the builder. Be firm but reasonable. Give them a reasonable amount of time to correct the problem and show they are working in good faith.

If the issue continues after the warranty period is over, it is still the responsibility of the builder, IF you can document that the issue started before the warranty period was over.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!  Yes it is actual brick.  The basement where the water is coming through is cinder block.
I asked the builder if sealant was applied to the brick, he stated no he has never heard of that?
So the sprinklers pummeled the side of the brick and the water seeped through trickling down the wall bypassing the exterior waterproofing that was done a week prior landing in the basement

Comment: Please dont use 2 logins. And please dont say thanks in an answer

Comment: 2 logins?  Not sure what you mean?